# Ubuntu freezing during startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, freeze

Ubuntu 18 and Windows are installed as dual boot on my [Acer Aspire F15](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/search?q=Aspire%20F15&src=support) laptop.

Since today my PC freezes completely when restarting, approximately 20 seconds after the grub screen to choose OS, typically at the login page. The same happens when booting to Windows or to Ubuntu from a live USB session.

However, it does NOT freeze when booting to Ubuntu in recovery mode.

Any idea what can cause such a freeze and how to solve it ?

My guess is that it's hardware related as it also freezes on Windows, but why is it not freezing in Ubuntu recovery mode ? Is recovery mode using less hardware ?

Comment: Suggest you remove and reinsert your memory modules; if there are two, reinstall only one before testing. If the problem clears, swap modules and retest, then reinsert the other and test with both.That will tell you if it's a specific module, or just connections.

Comment: Rather than touching/removing memory modules, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: If the memory test runs OK, then we'll look at your HDD/SSD.

Comment: SOP for all the testers in my shop to actually remove/reseat modules. Far quicker and more reliable results.

Comment: @K7AAY do your "testers" wear ESD bracelets?